# Двумерные массивы

Tags: java

Учу java по книге "java 2 Наиболее полное издание", вступил в штопор на многомерных массивах. Вот код:

```
class TwoDArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int twoD[][]= new int[4][5];
        int i, j, k = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                twoD[i][j] = k;
                k++;
            }

        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)  {  //должен выполниться 4 раза
            for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)   //однако второй цикл должен сработать 5 раз.
                System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Программа работает, но я не понимаю одну вещь. Цикл в цикле не укладывается у меня в уме. Объясните, пожалуйста, как это работает. Или, если можете, прокомментируйте каждую строку. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Второй цикл отработает 20 раз. Внешний цикл - четыре раза, а внутренний - по пять раз в каждой итерации внешнего цикла. При этом значения i и j будут меняться так

```
i, j
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
0, 4
1, 0
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
2, 0
2, 1
2, 3
2, 3
2, 4
3, 0
3, 1
3, 2
3, 3
3, 4
```

Answer (score 2):

А Вас смущает то, что цикл может повторятся?
Предлагаю вот это кусок

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)  {  //должен выполнится 4 раза
  for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)   //однако второй цыкл должен сработать 5 раз.
    System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
  System.out.println();
}
```

переписать так

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)  {  //должен выполнится 4 раза
  for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {  //однако второй цыкл должен сработать 5 раз.
    System.out.print("twoD["+i+"]["+j+"] = "+twoD[i][j]);
    System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

и посмотреть на вывод.
Цикл  - это повторение. Но ведь никто не мешает сделать одно повторение внутри другого.  Просто получится так, что строка `System.out.print("twoD["+i+"]["+j+"] = "+twoD[i][j]);` вызовется `4*5=20` раз.